# How to get birthdays from Contacts in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to create a simple app to get contact's birth dates. Below I have implemented some code, but I don't know what's actually going on.

```
var contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
    contactPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
    contactPicker.SelectionMode = ContactSelectionMode.Fields;
    contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);
    contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.Email);

    var contacts = await contactPicker.PickContactsAsync();
    if (contacts != null && contacts.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
            {
                var birthday = contact.ImportantDates.First(d => d.Kind == 
                      ContactDateKind.Birthday);
                textBlock.Text = birthday.Day.ToString();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            textBlock.Text = w.ToString();
        }                
    }
```

In above code I successfully get the email and name, but I can't get birthdays since there are no methods available like "contacts.birthday" Thank You.

The exception that I caught is:

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' in  System.Linq.dll 
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element at 
System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
predicate) at ContactApiSample.MainPage.<button_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: The error message says what's wrong. "Sequence contains no matching element." You ask for the first `ContactDate` that's a birthday, but what if there isn't one at all?

Comment: No but i have created one contact with the birthdate and i am trying with that one. Though i didn't get the birthday. But fortunately i found the way. Just look the below answer provided by  @GraceFeng , BTW thanks for reply.

Comment: But you didn't ask for the important dates to be returned. You didn't say `contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.ImportantDate);`

Comment: i do not want al importantDates but i just want birthday from the ImportantDate enum.

Comment: `ImportantDates` is a single field which you can request. That field happens to contain multiple important dates. There is currently no way to ask for only a specific important date. (Note that the workaround gets all of the important dates.)

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the only fields you can request from ContactPicker are Email, Phone, and Address. Other field requests are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using the [ContactPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactpicker.aspx) can not get all the information of contact. The count of the `IList<ContactDate> ImportantDates` is always 0.

I just found a workaround for your scenario, if you insist using `ContactPicker` here, you can get the contact's ID, and use this ID to find the same contact but from [ContactStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactstore.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for example like this:

```
if (contacts != null && contacts.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        ContactStore allAccessStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AppContactsReadWrite);

        foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
        {
            var storecontact = await allAccessStore.GetContactAsync(contact.Id);
            var birthday = storecontact.ImportantDates.First(d => d.Kind ==
          ContactDateKind.Birthday);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception w)
    {
        //textBlock.Text = w.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response @GraceFeng,  i have tried your work around and i got the desired result. Thank You . You made my day.